# Can I lessen the use of boolean flag variables in this snippet?

Tags: c#, performance, beginner, game, unity3d

Below snippet is part of a game application's logic and the `Update` function is called every frame (about 60 times a second).

```
void Update()
{
    handleInputEvents();
    if (bShow == true)
    {         
        if (bOnce)
        {
            button.show(true);
            bOnce = false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (bOnce == false)
        {
            button.show(false);
            bOnce = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to do what the above snippet is doing?

What the snippet is trying to achieve?
This snippet uses a `button.show()` function to update a virtual button's state. Everytime a physical button is pressed the state of virtual button is set to `true`(where true means the virtual button shows on screen and false means it doesn't) , as the physical button press is released, the state of the virtual button needs to be updated to `false`, meaning the virtual button will not show on the screen.

Problem: If `bOnce` flag check is not used, then the `button.show()` will be called every frame leading to more CPU cycles wasted.

The snippet shows my attempt to solve the problem.

Comment: When you need help with performance issues than you need to add more code, because the bottleneck may not be in the function you are showing us. Please post at least the entire class this code is a member of. Unlike Stack Overflow on Code Review we want to see more code rather than less code, please read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users/5778#5778)

Comment: @pacmaninbw With what I am allowed to share here, I can describe the class a bit more if you like, This is the only Update function for this class and rest are some methods for functionalities. If you have any queries, I will try to answer them here with the best of my ability.

Comment: "*`button.show()` will be called every frame leading to more CPU cycles wasted.*" - are you sure there? First thing I'd expect that method to do is to check whether the current state of the button already matches the requested state and return early if so.

Comment: Where is `bShow` defined? Can you show us the code where you are setting it?

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply summarise **the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Comment: "bShow" and "bOnce" suggest Hungarian naming, which Microsoft's naming conventions disapprove of.

Comment: @BCdotWEB Oh I thought the `b` stands for "button" :P

Comment: @TobySpeight thanks I will take a look and try to make sure the standards of my question match

Comment: @Bergi the `b` in `bShow` stands for it's type which is `bool`, and it's defined as part of the class member. Also to answer your concern, yes because the cpu cycles are used in calling a function, if the logic is present there then it's not very useful as the call instruction will be utilized and then there will be a return instruction taking up significant CPU cycles instead if I just check before calling the function then I can avoid using of CPU cycles every frame

Comment: @MukulKumar No, the call instruction is not *significant*.

Comment: Most answers here focus on making the boolean flags prettier, but [Unity provides a nice built-in solution](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/287213/235544) that completely obviates the need for these flags.

Comment: @ΞένηΓήινος thanks for the pep talk, you are misunderstanding the problem here, the checks are not the same, let me explain you in better way(I will try). The issue revolves around the fact that the function `button.show()` shouldn't be called at every `update()` call. The state of `bShow` may change whenever the physical button is pressed and in the next and the only next update call, the `button.show()` should be called, not in the following update calls. The thing with game logic is that `update()` function is called regardless of any conditions as part of the infinite loop,

Comment: continuing, hence instead of increasing a function call and return instructions per update call, I just check and skip the entire process in majority of `update()` calls hence saving precious CPU cycles.  please refer to a `game loop architecture` for better understanding of this issue.

Comment: @Bergi I doubt that a method call is cheaper than a boolean comparison.

Comment: @Taemyr I didn't say that it's cheaper, I said that is insignificant. Those few CPU cycles are not "precious", there's no loop involved or anything - it's a single call per frame. This is premature optimisation in a case where it doesn't matter.

Comment: @Bergi Well, I guess I should have said that I doubt the method call is less significant than a boolean comparison.

Answer (score 17):

> Can I lessen the use of boolean flag variables in this snippet?

Consider 1st comparing.

```
// bShow bOnce  Action
//   0     0    button.show(false); bOnce = true;
//   0     1    nothing
//   1     0    nothing
//   1     1    button.show(true); bOnce = false;
void Update() {
    handleInputEvents();
    if (bShow == bOnce) {         
      button.show(bShow); // or button.show(bOnce) whichever you find more clear.
      bOnce = !bOnce;
    }
}
```

Comment: Although `button.show(bOnce++);` is even less than `button.show(bOnce); bOnce = !bOnce;`, it looks strange to increment a `bool`, so I do not recommend it.

Comment: I would recommend `button.show(bShow)` over `button.show(bOnce)` though. Sure, they're guaranteed to be the same by the if condition, but still `bShow` is the intended button state and `bOnce` is just an optimisation.

Comment: @Bergi Sure....

Comment: I would change the name of `bOnce` to something like `bVisible` (and invert its value). That way you have one variable tracking the "desired" state, and another tracking the "actual" state. Then it's natural to write "if (actual_state != desired_state) { set_state(desired_state); actual_state=desired_state; }".

Comment: @psmears OP is quiet on how `bShow, bOnce` are determined.  Rather than that incremental change, I'd go for something [larger](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/287191/29485).

Comment: @chux: Fair enough, though actually I'd argue that your suggestion there is just one or two more incremental changes on top of what you have here plus the one I suggest...

Answer (score 10):

I'm not familiar with unity so, I can't review your code from that perspective. But we can certainly make this code more concise. Let me show you how to get started with refactor this code.

#### 1. Get rid of nested branching

Instead of having two levels of branching you can combine the conditions like this:

```
if (bShow && bOnce)
{         
    button.show(true);
    bOnce = false;
}
```

#### 2. Transform your else and if blocks to else if

It is basically the same thing what we did in the previous step

```
else if (!bShow && !bOnce)
{
    button.show(false);
    bOnce = true;
}
```

#### 3. Take a step back

Now we have only two branches so, it is much easier to overview what we have:

- If both variables are true then show button and set bOnce to false
- If both variables are false then hide button and set bOnce to true
- Otherwise do nothing

#### 4. Combine the conditions

We can combine the two conditions by saying either both true or both false

```
var bothTrue = bShow && bOnce;
var bothFalse = !bShow && !bOnce;
if (bothTrue || bothFalse)
```

Now, we just have to figure out how do we need to set `button.show` and `bOnce` values:

- The `button.show` is true if `bothTrue`
- The `bOnce` is true if `bothFalse`

#### 5. Let's put all this together

```
void Update()
{
    handleInputEvents();

    var bothTrue = bShow && bOnce;
    var bothFalse = !bShow && !bOnce;
    if (bothTrue || bothFalse)
    {         
        button.show(bothTrue);
        bOnce = bothFalse;
    } 
}
```

I hope it helped you a bit. :)

---

**UPDATE #1**

As it was mentioned by [user16217248](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/264812/user16217248) the condition can be simplified. If either both are true or both are false, that means their values are the same (`if (bShow == bOnce)`). Because `boolean`s could be either true or false.

If both of the variables are declared as `bool?` or `Nullable<bool>` then the shortened condition might not be suitable because in that case the condition would be evaluated as true if both are `null`. Which may or may not be the right solution depending on your requirements.

Comment: Yes definitely this looks far more professional than what I was able to cook, much grateful.

Yet I will wait for atleast a few days before acceptance.

Comment: We can probably put `bothTrue` and `bothFalse` variables as part of the class, so as to possibly reduce the allocation and deallocation process everytime the `Update()` is called. I am not sure though if local variables in C# behave this way, after being built to different platforms, for e.g WASM for web, Windows binary for Windows and so on.

Comment: @MukulKumar I would be less concerned about the memory footprint. If you want to optimize on the code then I would try to reduce the evaluation frequency. For example execute the Update only if one of the two variables' value has changed.

Comment: Nice work, although I'm not a big fan of the !a && !b syntax, I'd rather !(a || b) by way of de Morgan's Laws.

Comment: `var bothTrue = bShow && bOnce;
var bothFalse = !bShow && !bOnce;
if (bothTrue || bothFalse)` Why not just `if (bShow == bOnce)`?

Comment: I tried to focus on the refactoring process rather than how to write it in the most concise form. I showed step-by-step how get started with the refactoring BUT as it was pointed out by others this can be pushed further.

Answer (score 10):

Each call to `handleInputEvents()` can set bShow to a new boolean value.

We could approach the display update task by making a
[truth table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table).

```
| show | once  ||     XOR |     bothTrue | bothFalse | bT || bF |
|------+-------++---------+--------------+-----------+----------|
|    0 |    0  ||       0 |            0 |         1 |        1 |
|    0 |    1  ||       1 |            0 |         0 |        0 |
|    1 |    0  ||       1 |            0 |         0 |        0 |
|    1 |    1  ||       0 |            1 |         0 |        1 |
```

Looks like you want

```
    if (!(bShow ^ bOnce))
    {         
        button.show(bShow & bOnce);
        bOnce = !(bShow & bOnce);
    }
```

But those last two lines are already conditional, so this suffices:

```
    {         
        button.show(bShow);
        bOnce = !bOnce;
    }
```

Now the meaning is far more apparent.
We're simply copying, then flipping.
And what does the XOR mean?
It indicates "nothing changed",
so its negation is "something changed"
which the `if` body must deal with.

---

The bOnce state variable seems a clumsy way to express Author's Intent.
Yes, I understand that you want to call `button.show()` just once per change.
But why not express that notion directly?

Let bDisplayed cache the most recent `.show()` value we sent to the button.
Our goal is to keep the button in sync with bShow.

```
    handleInputEvents();
    if (bDisplayed != bShow)
    {         
        bDisplayed = bShow;
        button.show(bDisplayed);
    }
```

Now it is transparently obvious to the Gentle Reader
that bDisplayed closely tracks bShow,
and what is displayed *always* matches bDisplayed.
Keep the reader in mind when writing code.

> Programs must be written for people to read, and only incidentally for machines to execute.
>
> -- [SICP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_and_Interpretation_of_Computer_Programs), by Abelson and Sussman

Comment: I do find `bDisplayed == bShow` to be quite easier to read than `!(bDisplayed ^ bShow)`... Really.

Comment: plusGood for renaming variables into the UI domain. ALL refactorings not doing this are just "rearranging the deck chairs on the Titanic" so to speak; more tidy but not addressing the fundamental problem - obscuring understanding of just what is going on.

Answer (score 7):

Why don't you make `button.show()` simply do an early exit if the visibility state being passed in is already the same?   I'm surprised it doesn't already work this way.

```
void Button::show(bool visible) {
    if (visible == _currentVisibility) {
        return;
    }
    // complicated CPU intensive logic below
    _currentVisibility = visible;
}
```

Then you can skip all these variable checks and say:

```
void Update()
{
    handleInputEvents();
    button.show(bShow);
}
```

Can't change the `Button` control? Make a wrapper or use inheritance

```
class ButtonWrapper : public Button {
    std::optional<bool> _visibility;
    void ShowFast(bool visibility) {
        if (_visibility.hasValue() && *_visibility == visibility) {
            return
        }
        show(visibility);
        *_visibility = visibility;
    }
}
```

Or

```
class ButtonWrapper {
    std::optional<bool> _visibility;
    Button* _b;
public:
    ButtonWrapper(Button *b) : _b(b) {}
    void ShowFast(bool visibility) {
        if (_visibility.hasValue() && *_visibility == visibility) {
            return
        }
        _b->show(visibility);
        *_visibility = visibility;
    }
}
```

Comment: The original code is C#... not C++. Would be nice if the wrapper snippets were C# too. Otherwise, I definitely agree that this encapsulating the optimization is the best way to go.

Comment: DoublePlusGood for renaming variables into the UI domain. Here it is better than [my original comment above](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/287163/can-i-lessen-the-use-of-boolean-flag-variables-in-this-snippet#comment571788_287175). ALL refactorings not doing this are just "rearranging the deck chairs on the Titanic" so to speak; more tidy but not addressing the fundamental problem - obscuring understanding of just what is going on

Comment: The best answer!  Masterfully refactored. Concise thanks to detail encapsulation. `Show()` local variables instantly clarify just what is going on without requiring a universal variable renaming. Potential side effects are minimized; an example of  how Open/Close Principle can be applied. Future variable name improvements are not risking naming collsions.

Comment: `ButtonWrapper` class is premature. An ill advised suggestion without knowing the larger design context. The premise - "Can't change the Button control?" - seems to disregard the Button class API.  Also, pointer notation is foreign to C# coders. Underscore-prefixed-variables is the same sin as type-prefixed-names; it's not better OO if it is C++ idiomatic.

Answer (score 6):

Since this is tagged [unity3d](/questions/tagged/unity3d), rather than setting a flag somewhere else in the script, you can just do the following:

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("<physical button name>")
        button.show(true);

    if (Input.GetButtonUp("<physical button name>")
        button.show(false);
}
```

`Input.GetButtonDown` only returns true the first frame the button is pressed; likewise for `Input.GetButtonUp`.

A more comprehensive solution might be using the [Unity Input System](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.7/manual/index.html), which is more event driven, but might also be overkill if you don't need the flexibility the system provides.

Answer (score 4):

You currently have two booleans, capable of representing 4 states (like many other answers have shown with helpful truth tables). But there's actually only 3 cases here: show, hide, and do nothing. If you can change how `handleInputEvents` works, one nullable boolean should be enough to handle it all:

```
bool? bShow = null;

void Update() {
    handleInputEvents();

    if (bShow.HasValue) {
        button.show(bShow.Value);
        bShow = null;
    }
}

void handleInputEvents() {
    // Set bShow to true if there's been input to show the button,
    // set it to false if there's been input to hide the button,
    // and otherwise don't set it at all.
}
```

Unrelated, but I can't help pointing this out:

Unless you need the `bShow` value elsewhere in your code, I would recommend making `handleInputEvents` **return** the data representing the results (just the `bool?`, or a struct or a tuple if it resolves multiple things), instead of assigning to a field and reading it later. That way the dependencies are clear – your button-showing code depends on input handling.

```
// For example
struct InputResult {
    public bool? showButton;
    public bool? sayHello;
}

void Update() {
    var result = handleInputEvents();

    if (result.showButton.HasValue) {
        button.show(result.showButton.Value);
    }
}

InputResult handleInputEvents() {
    var result = new InputResult();
    // Populate the struct
    return result;
}
```

An even better option could be inverting control and using event-driven/reactive programming, where you can get rid of booleans like this altogether. :)

Comment: Thanks for valuable input, I will checkout `event-driven/reactive programming`

Answer (score 2):

I think a *higher level review* of how this whole button thing works.

I want to express a slightly different approach and instead of `bShow` and `bOnce` (which are not that clearly defined, especially `bOnce`) and use `physical_button` and `virtual_button` defined as below.

- `physical_button` the most recent sampled electrical signal of the real physical button.
- `virtual_button` is the state of the displayed button that the user sees.

I'd like to use 3 states: 0, 1 with their usual meaning of off/on and -1 implying unknown.  This -1 useful for initialization.

```
int physical_button = -1;  // or perhaps type signed char for these 2.
int virtual_button = -1;

void UpdateAlt() {
  handleInputEvents();
  // Unless the physical button has been sampled at least once, nothing to do.
  // ... and display deserves to remain in its initial state. 
  if (physical_button >= 0) { // This test useful if physical_button can be reset to -1.
    if (virtual_button != physical_button) {
      virtual_button = physical_button;
      button.show(virtual_button);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `if (physical_button >= 0)` seems unnecessary unless at some point you want to reset `physical_button` (but not `virtual_button`) to the "unknown" state

Comment: Yes, `physical_button` is `-1` at program start, but so is `virtual_button`, which means that the `virtual_button != physical_button` condition makes `physical_button >= 0` unnecessary.

Comment: @Bergi OK, I agree with your point that `if (physical_button >= 0)` is needed when "at some point you want to reset `physical_button`".

Answer (score 2):

I'd do:

```
void Update()
{
    handleInputEvents();
    if (bShow != bShown) {   // if the display doesn't match reality
        button.show(bShow);  // update the display to match
        bShown = bShow;      // and remember that for future checks
    }
}
```

(personally, I'm not fond of prefixing variable names with their type, but I take it that is a convention for the technology you are working in?)

Comment: type-prefixing variable names is contrary to OO principles and goals; it is not idiomatic C#. In fact OO nirvana can be said to be when the code is virtually oblivious to type - just ask Alan Kay. Variables should say what they are or are doing, not the implementation details of how.